# Problem with switch statement in language picker - [Solved]

Tags: templating, localization

I made a language picker, it works in one language but not in other. I want to get the current page of other locale.

```
{% set locale = craft.i18n.getCurrentLocale() %}

 {% switch locale %}

  {% case 'en_us' %}
   <a href="{{ craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale('de').first().url }}">Deutsch
  {% case 'de' %}
   <a href="{{ craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale('en_us').first().url}}">English

 {% endswitch %}
```

Works in first case but not the second. What am i doing wrong?

Update: I forget to update the locale template in other language. Problem is solved, my mistake.

Comment: Have to ask: is the entry enabled for both locales?

Comment: Yes all entries and sections enabled.

Comment: And what happens in case the current locale is 'de'? Is that switch case even reached? What gets displayed if you put 'test' after {% case 'de' %}? Or if you do {{ dump(craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale('en_us').first()) }} there? Is devMode set to true, to see if any errors are thrown?

Comment: Oh, i am so dumb. i forget to use the same code in other locale template! Thanks for helping.

Comment: Wait, so you have a different template for each locale? In that case, you might try to include code snippets like the one above from a single source, so you don't have to change 'm for every locale.

Comment: Yes i complete copy all templates. Although i have header template, my navigation have slight variance in different language. Will do your advice in my next project.

Comment: Can you add your fix as an official answer, @orionlogic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget to update locale template code with the same switch statement. Now problem solved.